# How to make chrome extension 'optional permissions' dialog pop up locally?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm trying to get this
[optional permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hoS4.png) to pop up locally while testing

I've been following this official tutorial:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/permissions/

In my case, the optional permission dialog should ideally activate when the button of class '.cbtn' is clicked on my website.

Here is chrome.permission.request part of my background.js file

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.querySelector('.cbtn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      console.log('now activating prompt!!');
      chrome.permissions.request({
        permissions: ["bookmarks"]
      }, function(granted){
        // The callback argument will be true if the user granted the permissions.
        if (granted) {
          // doSomething();
          console.log('Access granted');
        } else {
          // doSomethingElse();
          console.log('Access denied');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Note: My manifest.json doesn't contain permission for bookmarks.

In the chrome://extensions/?errors for my unpacked extension, i see an error message-
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

I don't know if that is because it's trying to find .cbtn on the chrome://extensions/ page itself instead of on my particular website where a button with class .cbtn actually exists,

Will appreciate any help, pointers on this